# Blender via SSH stops rendering if I disconnect

Tags: rendering, linux

So I'm running the Blender in UI-less mode to render animation on my linux server.

Everything works smooth, but one thing does really bother me - if I disconnect from SSH (for example, if I close the PuTTY) the Blender stops rendering. Why?

And how can I make it work without me being always on the line?

Comment: Consider using `screen` or `tmux`: https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The session is closed when you disconnect from ssh. The solution is simple. You need to use **screen**

```
sudo apt-get install screen
```

(in case you are using Ubuntu)

Then do ssh normally.

Inside the ssh session, type

```
screen
```

Accept, and then run your process. Now, do not close the window. Press Ctrl, hold it while you press A, then hold both keys and press D.

Then the screen session is detached, the process is running in the background and you can exit your ssh session.

Later, you can ssh again. Your process will still be there. To recover the screen session, type

```
screen -r
```